# Collection of closures. Different invocation methods.

Tags: collections, groovy, closures

At work, we are discussing about a simple (or not so simple) question. ¿Is there any difference between the following invocation methods?

```
class Obj {
    def num
    def prtn = {
        print this.num
    }
}  
def listObj = [new Obj(num:1), new Obj(num:2), new Obj(num:3), new Obj(num:4)]  
// End Common code  

// Method #1  
def lst = listObj.collect{ obj-> obj.prtn() }  

// Method #2  
def lst = listObj.collect{ obj-> { -> obj.prtn()} }.each{ it() }  
// Common code
```

Answer (score 2):

The side-effect of both statements is the same: they print "1234". But the return value is different.

The `prtn` method always returns `null`, so the value of `listObj.collect{ obj-> obj.prtn() }` is `[null, null, null, null]`.

In the case of `listObj.collect{ obj-> { -> obj.prtn()} }.each{ it() }`, as [`each`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#each%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) returns the collection on which it was invoked, the result will be a list of Closure objects (as that is what `listObj.collect{ obj-> { -> obj.prtn()} }` returns).

In general, if you only want to iterate a collection for some side effect, use `each`; if you want to transform it into a different collection, use `collect`. And try no to mix both side-effect iteration and transformation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
listObj*.prtn()
```

And this gives the same result as your Method #1